# Symfony 2. Add field some css class when validation is false

Tags: validation, symfony, twig, constraints, symfony-forms

As example, i have code:

```
$builder->add('fieldname', null, array(
    'constraints' => array(
        new NotBlank(),
        new Length(array('min' => 3, 'max' => 255)),
    ),
));
```

How i can select field as red or add him some css class when validation is false?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use TWIG to add custom CSS class if the field is not validated. Here is how :

TWIG:

```
<div class="{{ fieldname.vars.errors|length > 0 ? 'field-has-error-class' : '' }}">
{{form.fieldname}}
</div>
```

This will add your custom-CSS error without the need of handling it with code.

hope this helps.